# Check whether an opentype math font is loaded

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontspec, opentype

How can I check (using a conditional, preferably) whether an opentype math font is currently loaded (in use)? For example, using the following commands:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT}
```

I would like to check (afterwards) if that specific font was really loaded and is been used in math mode. Does fontspec, unicode-math (or luaotfload)  provides such facility?

For the curious: I'm trying to correct what (I think) is a kerning problem with some accents in (some) opentype fonts with math support. For example, the picture below shows the output of `$\hat\jmath$` in Lucida OpenType (available from TUG) using LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX):

[image: jmath in Lucida Opentype]

Which one could correct with `$\skew{3}{\hat}{\jmath}$` but, unfortunately, every (problematic) font requires a different position adjustment parameter.

Comment: Too bad! This should be made known to the font developers.

Comment: @egreg They were notified and indeed the latest Lucida OpenType font version (v1.802) from TUG corrected those kind of problems with accents above dotless j and i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Macro `\l__um_fontname_tl` holds the name of the math font. However, it is the name that was given to `\setmathfont`. Therefore, the same font can have several names.
- Another way is to inspect one of the font name commands used for math.
  The command name also contains the font name.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
  The math font is \csname l__um_fontname_tl\endcsname.

  $
    \makeatletter
    \edef\x{\the\textfont2}
    \edef\x{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\x}
    \mbox{\ttfamily\x}
  $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]